# Where can I read more on this use of STRING in ruby `s = <<-STRING `

Tags: ruby, printing

I see this used sometimes.
Here is a method:

```
def show_intro
  s = <<-STRING
    Welcome to #{@nationwide.name}!
    -------------------------------
  STRING
  puts s.gsub(/^\s+/,'')
end
```

It is quite difficult to google since all that turns up is the generic info on string class in ruby.

Comment: Search for it as _heredoc_.

Comment: SymbolHound is often better at this sort of thing: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3C%3C-

Comment: Google "ruby heredoc". One near the top of Google's list will be [this article](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html) by Jay Fields. It's worth a read.